# Eliminar posicion de un arrays en java

Tags: java, array

estoy realizando un proyecto de la universidad sobre un sistema de banco, como haría para borrar la (cuenta bancaria) informacion de un elemento del array y actualizar?
mi codigo es este pero no me funciona:

```
public void Borrar_Datos() {

    try {
            System.out.print("Ingresar el Id a borrar: ");
            int id= Integer.parseInt(leer.readLine());

            if(id<=contSi) {

                for(int i=id; i<nombre.length-1; i++) {
                    nombre[i]= nombre[i+1];
                    cuenta[i]= cuenta[i+1];
                    contra_usu[i]= contra_usu[i+1];
                    contSi--;
                }

                System.out.println("\n\n\n");
                Menu(); 

            }else {
                System.out.println("El Id no existe");
                System.out.println("\n\n\n");
                Borrar_Datos();
            }

    }catch(Exception e) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Hola @lastcrow, puedes aclarar ¿Qué es `contSi` y cómo lo calculas? En cuanto a tu duda, vas a tener que usar otro `array` para almacenar los datos restantes luego que extraigas el que quieres eliminar.

Comment: @MauricioContreras esa variable es de tipo Static, me permite llevar el control de las posiciones de los arrays, a parte de eso puedo saber cuentos elementos e introducido en el array, ¿de que forma haría eso?

Comment: porque no usas una lista o un mapa te seria mas facil de codear y de depurar

Comment: lo otro es que lo hagas manualmente pero el costo computacional sera elevado...quiero decir encuentras el id del elemento y lo que haces es hacer otro for actualizando la pos_actual en pos_actual+1 me entiendes?

Comment: Tienes 3 `array` diferentes, uno para nombre, otro para cuenta y otro para password. ¿Cómo es eso?

Answer (score 2):

Seria asi

```
int [] bankAccount=new int[100];

    for(int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
    {
        int id = 1+new Random().nextInt(100);

        System.out.println("id: " + id);
        bankAccount[i]=id;
    }

    int id = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();

    for(int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
    {
        if(bankAccount[i]==id)
        {
            //eliminamos esa cuenta
            for(int j = i; j <= 12; j++)
                bankAccount[j]=bankAccount[j+1];
            break;
        }
    }

    //hasta 11 xq eliminaste uno

    for(int i = 1; i<= 11; i++)
        System.out.println(bankAccount[i] + " ");
```

Esto es solo un ejemplo para que veas, sugiero que lo hagas con un mapa que es algo mas dinamico para eliminar e insertar. Salu2